# Default width/height of an IFrame

Tags: html, iframe, specifications

Is there any spec specifying the default width/height of an IFrame?

Browsers I tested (FF, IE, Chrome) seem to use 300x150px but I couldn't find any spec on this. Should I ever come in the situation, can I rely on these values or should I always set width/height explicitly?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I found the answer on the [dev-tech-layout mailing list](http://mozilla.6506.n7.nabble.com/Where-does-default-size-of-iframe-come-from-td230992.html#message230993) -- it's part of the CSS spec. The *default ratio* is **2:1**.

The *default width* of **300px** is defined in the last paragraph of the CSS spec, section on [the width of inline replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width).

> Otherwise, if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the
>   conditions above are met, then the used value of 'width' becomes
>   300px. If 300px is too wide to fit the device, UAs should use the
>   width of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio and fits the
>   device instead.

The *default height* of **150px** is defined in the last paragraph of the CSS spec, section on [the height of inline replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height).

> Otherwise, if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the
>   conditions above are met, then the used value of 'height' must be set
>   to the height of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio, has a
>   height not greater than 150px, and has a width not greater than the
>   device width.

Comment: Great find! Have you found out which version of which browser implements this part of the spec?

Answer (score 7):

I would set the width and height explicitly to ensure consistent rendering across multiple browsers/platforms as there is no guarantee that every browser will implement the same default dimensions.

```
<iframe src="iframePage.html" width="100%" height="300px">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>
```

Comment: It doesn't really answers the question =(

Comment: Sure it does: "should I always set width/height explicitly?"