# Flex iframe doesn't stretch in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, flexbox

The following `iframe` is a flex item and is supposed to stretch and fill the available space:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Flex Iframe</title>
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            margin: 0;
            height: 100vh;
        }
        span {
            background: green;
        }
        iframe {
            background: tan;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <span>Hello, world!</span>
    <iframe></iframe>
</body>

</html>
```

But in IE11 it doesn't look right:
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/Fm8C3/)**

Is it a bug? What's a cross-browser solution?

Comment: use javascript to get the available width and height and set the iframe with the given values. if it also should work when the window is resized, use an eventlistener to change the width/heigth of the iframe.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's easy:

```
iframe {
            min-height: 100%;
        }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm8C3/33/)**

Comment: I had a similar problem: the presence of a style tag inside the iframe made the iframe's height shrink. It only affected Internet Explorer, but this solution fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

From : [Default width/height of an IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871668/default-width-height-of-an-iframe)
<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Fm8C3/5/)**</kbd>

"...I found the answer on the [dev-tech-layout mailing list](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Fm8C3/5/) -- it's part of the CSS spec. The *default ratio* is **2:1**..."

"...The *default width* of **300px** is defined in the last paragraph of the CSS spec, section on [the width of inline replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width)..."

> Otherwise, if 'width' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the
>   conditions above are met, then the used value of 'width' becomes
>   300px. If 300px is too wide to fit the device, UAs should use the
>   width of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio and fits the
>   device instead.

"...The *default height* of **150px** is defined in the last paragraph of the CSS spec, section on [the height of inline replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-height)..."

> Otherwise, if 'height' has a computed value of 'auto', but none of the
>   conditions above are met, then the used value of 'height' must be set
>   to the height of the largest rectangle that has a 2:1 ratio, has a
>   height not greater than 150px, and has a width not greater than the
>   device width.

---

You not given height to `iframe` so its taking the original height of iframe in IE try below

```
body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100vh;
}
span {
    background: green;
}
iframe {
    background: tan;
    height: 100vh; /* this is required to give it height in IE */
    border:0; /* toavoid vertical scroll */
}
```

Here it is

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm8C3/24/)</kbd>

using the `calc` for height, modern browsers support `calc`

css

```
body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px);
    flex-direction: column;
}
span {
    background: green;
    height:calc(100vh - 50px);
}
iframe {
    background: tan;
    height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* this is required to give it height */
    border:0; /* to avoid vertical scroll */
}
header {
    background: yellow;
    height:50px;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
```

<kbd>**[Final Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/Fm8C3/28/)**</kbd>

Use of a some jquery to achieve the same

jQuery

```
// If you put your code at the bottom of the page to avoid needing`$(document).ready`, it gets even simpler:

$(window).on('resize', function () {
    var demoheight = $(window).height() - $('header').height();
    $("body, iframe, span").css("height", demoheight);
}).trigger('resize');



// Another way to do that same thing

// $(document).ready(myfunction);
// $(window).on('resize', myfunction);

// function myfunction() {
  //  var demoheight = $(window).height() - $('header').height();
  //  $("body, iframe, span").css("height", demoheight);
// }



// Another technique is to`.trigger()`one event inside the other:

// $(window).on('resize', function () {
   // var demoheight = $(window).height() - $('header').height();
   // $("body, iframe, span").css("height", demoheight);
// });
// $(document).ready(function () {
   // $(window).trigger('resize');
// });
```

CSS

```
body {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    flex-direction: column;
}
span {
    background: green;
}
iframe {
    background: tan;
    border:0;
}
header {
    background: yellow;
}
main {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what if things get a little complicated like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/Mori/Fm8C3/17/)?

Comment: Your solution works if I can give a fixed height to the header. But in my situation, the header content and height are not fixed and that's why I'm using a flexible layout.

Answer (score 0):

Look this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/grrenier/cm4f3/1/

You can use position fixed for the body and work with % for all elements. This is the code:

HTML:

```
<header>Some text</header>
<span>Hello, world!</span>
<iframe></iframe>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    background: yellow;
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
    float:left;
}
span {
    background: green;
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    height:95%;
}
iframe {
    background: tan;
    width:85%;
    height:95%;
    border:0;
}
```

You don't need to use `<main>` tag but if you use it you can use position fixed too.

This is another fiddle using `<main>` tag http://jsfiddle.net/grrenier/chT8F/

HTML:

```
<header>Some text</header>
<main>
<span>Hello, world!</span>
<iframe></iframe>
</main>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;
    margin: 0;
}
header {
    background: yellow;
    width:100%;
    height:5%;
    float:left;
}
span {
    background: green;
    float:left;
    width:15%;
    height:100%;
}
iframe {
    background: tan;
    width:85%;
    height:100%;
    border:0;
    float:left;
}
main {float:left;height:95%;width:100%;}
```

Comment: Your solution works if I can give a fixed height to the header. But in my situation, the header content and height are not fixed and that's why I'm using a flexible layout. So is the span and iframe width.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `display: inline-block` to the span
2. Add a div around the iframe and make it `display: flex`
3. Add `flex-direction: column` to the div
4. Apply `flex: 1` to the iframe.

**Examples:**

[Simple](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm8C3/30/)

[More complex](http://jsfiddle.net/Fm8C3/29/)

Comment: And what's the extra scrollbar in your 2nd demo?

Answer (score 0):

To have an iframe fill a parent.. works in chrome, ie and edge.

**min-height:100%;** is the key for ie.

```
<td rowspan="9" style="position:relative;padding:0;width:270px;">
    <iframe class="readonly" style="position:absolute;width:100%;min-height:100%;top:0;bottom:0;right:0;left:0;" src="page.php"></iframe>
</td>
```