# How to make iframe fit width near floating image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

How to make the width of an Iframe fit the remaining width of the parent element when there's a floating element beside it?

Code example: https://jsfiddle.net/1r1o87c0/

```
<div id="parent">
<p>
Aenean id nisl elit. Phasellus<img class="alignright" src="http://placehold.it/200x200"> porta nunc vitae porta.
</p>
<div id="iframe_wrap"><iframe src="http://example.com/" scrolling="no" frameborder="no"></iframe></div>
<p>
Nullam eleifend est tempus felis dignissim luctus. eugiat pulvinar ac non mauris.
</p>
</div>
```

Right now the Iframe size is 300x150px, which is [defined by the CSS specs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871668/default-width-height-of-an-iframe).
Setting the iframe width to auto doesn't seem to work, and setting it to 100% obviously just pushes it down after the floating image.

I don't mind to use JS...

Comment: what is ur expected output?

Comment: Is this responsive ? Or is your floated image static? you can use `width: calc(100% - 380px)`

Comment: @G.L.P I want the iframe to extend all the way until the floating image

Comment: @JoelAlmeida I prefer not to use CSS3, which is still considered [experimental](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc). Also, where is the 380px coming from?...

Comment: @Lulu it's 350px from the image, and 30px of margin. and about the `calc()` check browser support: http://caniuse.com/#search=calc

Comment: @JoelAlmeida You are right, i still prefer not to use CSS3. any other suggestions?

Comment: @Lulu the only suggestion I can give you is to define the width of the `iframe`.

Comment: @JoelAlmeida In that case, is there any way to calculate the width left empty (parent_width - floating_element_width - margins)?

Comment: Can You change markup?
[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1r1o87c0/2/)

Comment: @BogdanKuštan yes I can, but mind that the floating element is dynamic on the real world, so I need to find its width dynamically