# Object: html insert takes up too much height

Tags: html, spacing

I am working on a fairly simple HTML page for a JavaScript star-drawing program I've written and have run into some trouble. Since I want the top section of each page to be the same, I figured I could write an html file for that part of the page and insert that into the individual pages. I used `<object>` to do this and it basically works but takes up a lot of space in the page (I added a red border around the object to show this clearly):

[code result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gK9QN.png)

My page's code is:

```
<html>
<body>
  <object data="drawthestars-header.html" style="border: 1px solid red;">
    error loading file
  </object>
  <p><b>Draw a star?</b></p>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>Points: </td>
      <td><input type="text" value="15" id="deg" size="3" maxLength="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><label>Jump: </label></td>
      <td><input type="text" value="6" id="jump" size="3" maxLength="3"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><button id="redraw" onclick="addStar()">Draw</button></td>
      <td><button id="clear" onclick="clearAll()">Clear</button>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <br />

  <div id="stars"></div>

  <script src="drawthestars.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

drawthestars-header.html, the inserted code, is just:

```
<a href="#">link???</a>
```

Could someone point me to what's going wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be the default IFrame element size, which the object element actually is behind the scene.

[Default width/height of an IFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871668/default-width-height-of-an-iframe)

You should set the width and height of the object element to change that.