# iFrame has fixed width of 300px, without any styling defining 300px

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I'm using the iframe-resizer package to dynamically change the size of an iframe depending on content.

However, before even trying any dynamic resizing, I run into an issue with the basic iframe: it's **always** `300px` in width. Whatever content I place inside the iframe, the width is always 300px. Will not move; overflow is hidden if I add something >300px and still takes up 300px if my content is smaller than that.

**EDIT: To be clear, My problem is that I want to dynamically change the width of an iframe (cross-domain), but it always renders at 300px and will not change. I'm using the iframe-resizer package to successfully dynamically change the height, but that's nto working on the width.**

In the parent site, I'm embedding the iframe as follows:

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@4.2.11/js/iframeResizer.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search).get("openWidget"); document.write('<iframe id="inlineFrameExample" title="Inline Frame Example" style="position: fixed; zIndex: 1000; bottom: 0; right: 0" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" src="http://localhost:3001?openWidget=' + i + '"></iframe>');
    window.iFrameResize({ log: true }, '#inlineFrameExample')
</script>
```

And the content in my for my framed site, I have the following elements and styling:

```
    <div className="App" id="App2">
      {openWidget && <div className="button">OK</div>}
      {showMessage && <section>This is a message</section>}
      <div>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => setShowMessage(!showMessage)}>
          Msg
        </button>
        <button className="button" onClick={() => setOpenWidget(!openWidget)}>
          {openWidget ? "-" : "+"}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>

.App {
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  float: right;
}

section {
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  color: white;
  width: 500px;
}

.button {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: mediumseagreen;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  float: right;
}
```

Note that there's nothing in there about width being 300px. There are other widths, but the iframe seems to ignore them and always set itself to 300px.

I also made two code sandboxes, and embedded one site in the other via an iframe. Unfortunately the iframe is hidden for some reason, but if you inspect and look for the iFrame with id="inlineFrameExample" (and not code sandbox's button iframe) you'll see it's 300px wide: https://exzts.csb.app/
The code for the parent site is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-flower-exzts?file=/index.html
The code for the framed site is here: https://codesandbox.io/s/iframe-test-ss8fs

UPDATE: I also removed all css styling from both the parent site and the framed site. Still always stuck at 300px. I also viewed the [CSS specs](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) which says default will be default set to 300px under certain conditions, but I cannot figure out how to dissatisfy those conditions so that the 300px rule doesn't apply.

I want the iframe to resize based on width. The current set up works perfectly on height, and I understand there's something in the default specs for iframes that sets them to 300px if x conditions are met: w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width What I need is whatever styling/setting/attribute will disable this, so the width will act in the same way as the height (i.e. completely dynamic).

Comment: Default iframe width is 300px, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871668/default-width-height-of-an-iframe.  Did you try setting width: 100% or something?

Comment: @James I did set `width:100%` on the iframe itself (where I embedded it in the parent site), but that caused it to take up the whole 100vw of the parent site. Should I be setting it elsewhere?

Comment: @tao Edited my post. Also already put those things in the bounty request.

Comment: So you want the iframe to set its own width based on its contents? That's simply not achievable. It's like you'd expect a webpage to resize the browser. That's pretty much what the iframe element is for its contents. Also, that's not a very good place to define the requirement. That text will go away once the bounty expires. And your question doesn't make much sense without it, hence my question above. I'd move it in the question.

Comment: @tao So, if I'm understanding correctly, the iframe can only set its own height based on its contents, and not its own width?

Comment: To simplify: you can't determine an element's `height` without declaring the available `width`. The `<iframe>`'s body element doesn't look at its contents to get the available width. It looks up. And gets `300px` available width, because you haven't set a `width` on the `<iframe>` and that's the default. Why is the default `300px`? I don't know. Does it matter? To me it would make more sense to be `100%`. It can be easily set to `100%`. It's only a default value.

Comment: Another point: `<iframe>` is the wrong tool for the job. You're basically presenting an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). I can create an app which controls part of a document (a few inline elements), effectively resulting in *"variable, inline width"*, which seems to be what you're after. If I can achieve this using Vue, I'm sure it can be achieved with React or Svelte. So why are you trying to make `<iframe>`s work other than designed when you don't even need an `<iframe>` to achieve the desired behavior?

Comment: I guess the "X" then would be: I need to embed my variable, inline width widget on third party sites. I'm aware of the possibility of doing this with `script` tags, but there are also examples out there of widgets being embedded via `iframe` tags. I asked my question because I'm still in what you'd call a "discovery phase" - researching the possibilities and limitations. I now understand this is a limitation.

Comment: "I want the iframe to resize based on width." based on which width? The one of the iframe's container? Set `width: 100%` in the CSS. The one of the iframe's content? When? If the iframe's content is responsive you may very well end in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iframe-resizer doesn't resize iframe width by default. You have to explicitly specify it using [sizeWidth](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/docs/parent_page/options.md#sizewidth) setting.

```js
window.iFrameResize({
  log: false,
  sizeWidth: true,
  checkOrigin: false,
  widthCalculationMethod: "rightMostElement",
  heightCalculationMethod: "lowestElement"
}, "#myFrame");
```

```css
body { background-color: wheat;}
iframe { border: 3px dashed green; }
span { font-size: 1.5rem;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@4.2.11/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>

<div>Following iframe grows automatically!</div>
<iframe id="myFrame" scrolling="no" src="https://mvyom.csb.app/"></iframe>
<span></span>
```

The iframe content is animated so it affects iframe's width and height according to the specified width and height calculation methods. And the iframe-resizer updates dimensions on every animations start and end event.

Also, the iframe source is from [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mvyom?file=/index.html) and the parent document is this StackOverflow answer page, so we need to set `checkOrigin: false` as well.

**Note:** Had to set `log: false` because the animations are happening very fast creating ton of logs in console.

---

You can provide your own size calculations form inside the iframe.[ref](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/iframe-resizer/blob/master/docs/iframed_page/options.md):

```html
    <script>
      window.iFrameResizer = {
        widthCalculationMethod: function () {
          return document.querySelector(".one").clientWidth;
        }
      };
    </script>
```

In following demo the iframe resizes exactly to the width of green box.

```js
window.iFrameResize({
  log: false,
  sizeWidth: true,
  checkOrigin: false,
  widthCalculationMethod: "rightMostElement",
  heightCalculationMethod: "lowestElement"
}, "#myFrame");
```

```css
body { background-color: wheat;}
iframe { border: 3px dashed green; }
span { font-size: 1.5rem;}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/iframe-resizer@4.2.11/js/iframeResizer.min.js"></script>

<div>Following iframe grows automatically!</div>
<iframe id="myFrame" scrolling="no" src="https://mvyom.csb.app/custom.html"></iframe>
<span></span>
```

Refer implementation of [custom.html](https://codesandbox.io/s/mvyom?file=/custom.html:1321-1501) for better understanding. You can implement similar method for `heightCalculationMethod`.

Comment: I'm still struggling a lot with CSS (I have this weird issue where my iframe grows to fit the text on first reveal, then gets gradually smaller on each subsequent reveal), BUT this answer is the best demonstration that it's possible, so I will accept it as correct.

Comment: I've added possible solution to the answer. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you   I will try this out later.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understand the question. I think you've made an App and a page. On the page you want to use an iframe to show your App and the iframe should be scaled by default to the size of the app. Did I get that right?

I think JavaScript might by your solution. Get the content from the iframe, check in the content for a class App en that's the width you want to use for your iframe.

```
const iframe = document.querySelector("#inlineFrameExample");
const iWindow = iframe.contentWindow;
const iDocument = iWindow.document;
const iElement = iDocument.querySelector(".App");

iframe.style.width = iElement.style.width;
```

A problem with this script is that it can only be executed after the content from the iframe was loaded. So make sure you wait for that with a timer,delay, promise, or something. If you don't want to show the resizing to your visitors make sure the iframe has visibilty: hidden and add visibilty: visible of the iframe to the end of the script above.

Comment: I don't think this works, because the app in the iframe isn't intialised when the parent page loads -- but this script also runs when the parent page loads. Tried adding async await in there but also didn't work (and started to get messy).

Comment: I've just read in another comment from you that a client is suppossed to press a button and after that event the iframe is loaded. As the iframe won't dynamically resize it's width I still think you could use the above method, but another option would be (but really messy) to do a XMLHttpRequest to the page or stylesheet that will be loaded. Get the responseText and from there get to the width of the content. If you do this request before loading the iframe you'll know how wide it needs to be and you can set it's width.

Answer (score 0):

## The good news

If the page loaded by the iframe is on the same domain as yours, then you can easily find out the initial state by defining an `onload` attribute to the `iframe` and then access the `contentWindow` of the `iframe` and do some measurements and then apply them on your main page. But, as you said, the content of the `iframe` is from another origin. Bad luck, read on.

## Some hope

Well, we know that you cannot directly access the content of the `iframe`. But, the content of the `iframe` may let you know when certain events happen. If the content inside the `iframe` does send messages, then you can `addEventListener` for `message` type events and specify the `origin` to be the site you are using inside the `iframe`. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

So, the site inside the `iframe` does some messaging? Maybe yes. But probably not. If it does not message you at the time of events of interest, then read on.

## The bad news

Modern browsers do not allow you to directly run Javascript at other origins due to security reasons. One obvious example for this is that cookies can be read for a page and you absolutely do not want some third-party sites to mess with your cookies while you are doing a banking transactions or something of the like.

## Some glimmer of hope

You may be able to somehow determine the current state of the `iframe`s content. For example you may have access to API functions or something of the like that you can ask about your status. If those are leaking direct information about your situation inside the `iframe` (was the button clicked already, for instance?), then you may be able to [poll](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/polling-in-javascript-ab2d6378705a) such a source and see whenever a size changing event happens and if so your code could adapt your view accordingly. This way you would use another source of information to find out what is happening inside the `iframe`.

## Sad but true

In general, the answer to your main question is **NO**. The explanation is that **it is not allowed due to security reasons**.

You may have some workarounds in your specific situation that may work out for you, but such workarounds are rarely available, most websites are working without providing supports for other websites that would like to use them in iframes. If the workarounds are not available for you, then you may want to reach out to the owner of the website shown in your `iframe` and see whether he/she is okay with providing support for this. Otherwise you will have to accept that the situation is beyond repair. Is it? If you are not satisfied yet, read on.

## Desperation

If you really, really need to resolve this, then here's what you can do:

- create a page in the same domain as your main page
- from the browser's point of view both your main page and the page inside the `iframe` are using the very same domain, so they can reach each-other via Javascript
- this new page will request the site to be shown in the `iframe` where the page of the other domain was shown previously (you don't create a further nested `iframe`, you just change its `src`)
- and it will display it
- but you add a little bit of Javascript, doing some measurements
- and of course you adjust resource URLs accordingly, changing all relative URLs into absolute URLs

This might work, but it's very cumbersome and you will always need to adjust the given page whenever the site you are to use changes.

Comment: "but you add a little bit of Javascript, doing some measurements", like what? How having the iframe being nested once more solves anything? Your inner-doc won't be able to access its iframe's content either.

Comment: @Kaiido you misunderstood the last section. The configuration in that case is that you have two pages of **your** domain, an outer page and a page inside the iframe. The page inside the iframe is using the **same** domain, that is, you have no trouble accessing the iframe's content from the outer page. The iframe, on the other hand is requesting **your** page at the backend. But on the backend **your** page is doing the requests to the other domain. So, your **server** does the requests to the other domain and from your browser's perspective there is an outer and an iframe page of the same...

Comment: @Kaiido ... domain. So **there is no further nesting** involved into this idea. Instead, the communication with the other domain is delegated to the back-end, bypassing browser CORS policy.

Comment: Then your answer is unclear as it's really not what it is saying. But anyway, I believe you missed the point of this question that the other answer got correctly.

Comment: @Kaiido thank you for your critical observations. I would like to clarify my answer. Can you show me the quote from this answer according to which one needs to create an iframe inside the iframe? I do not find it and while it is clear there was a misunderstanding here, I do not understand yet which part of the answer is the culprit.

Comment: "this new page will request the site to be shown in an iframe"

Comment: @Kaiido thanks! Changed it to "this new page will request the site to be shown in the iframe where the page of the other domain was shown previously (you don't create a further nested iframe, you just change its src)" in order to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

@crevulus, the inner content of iframe has no impact on the dimensions of it's parent iframe by design

Also, as far as I remember, 300x150px is the common default width and height applied by browsers to any «iframe» element faced in html code on parsing incoming html and building the DOM stages, when the dimentions have been not predefined explicitely

The thing is a browser requires the dimentions of any visible element (i.e. any element that takes space in page layout - for simplicity, let's say any element except those where «display» property has been set to «none») either to be strictly predeclared with «width» and «height» properties (via element attributes with the same names, via internal / external css rule or css rule applied to element directly thru «style» attribute - the way doesn't matter) or to be calculable thru initial (default) values defined in html / css standards (again, for simplicity, if «div» element has no dimentions set, but all the neighbours do, its width will be calculated by browser as all available horizontal space between the left and right neighbours of the element, i.e. the «div» will always have initial width, defined by standard, which equals 100%; similary, the height of this «div» will be calculated as sum of heights of all its internal elements) - the dimentions are strictly required because w/o concrete values for every visible element on page a browser won't be able to render the page content for the current viewport correctly

So, when a browser parses incoming html code and faces «iframe» elements with no predefined dimentions (via attributes, css et cetera), to allocate the space for the element in page layout and thus to be able to move on to parse / render the whole page, a browser assumes the dimentions of the «iframe» as common defaults, which, as I mentioned above, equals square figure 300x150px («recumbent skyscraper»)

To override this behaviour, you should predeclare in any convenient way initial values, which will be suitable for your case

```html
<iframe id="frame1" width="100%" height="250px" />
```

or

```html
<style>
#frame1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 250px;
}

</style>
<iframe id="frame1" />
```

et cetera, and then, when a page is rendered, if needed, use JavaScript to tune the dimensions of this iframe accoring to the width and height of its content (or any other condition on your choice), like

```
var frame1 = document.getElementById('frame1')
var width1 = parseFloat(frame1.style.getPropertyValue('width')) | 0
var height1 = parseFloat(frame1.style.getPropertyValue('height')) | 0

/*
 * some stuff to define the conditions for iframe dimentions tuning and 
 * to calculate new width and height and to assing calculated values
 * to width1 and height1 variables respectively
 */

frame1.style.setProperty('width', width1 + 'px')
frame1.style.setProperty('height', height1 + 'px')
```

As a postscript I'd like to note the above is the working concept, 'cause a few month ago I've designed and developed the close scheme to force the iframe of TinyMCE editor, built in Magento 1.9.x admin backend, to keep editor's width always equal to the width of CMS page on site's frontend and to expand / shrink editor's height dynamically accoring to the height of CMS page content being edited

The goal was to simplify and optimise the working process for the content department by making CMS pages in Magento admin area always look in TinyMCE editor exactly the same as on site's frontend

Unfortunately, the whole 1st gen of Magento, up to the last 1.9.4.5 release, is supplied with unspeakable outdated release of TinyMCE editor - 3rd gen of TinyMCE, published in early 2014 even before html5 officially arrived, in comparison even with it's own current 5th gen (which, in turn, frankly, is much inferior to alternative modern lightweight apps of WYSIWYG class) for 2022 feels like the Stone Age, a clumsy craft developed with stone axe by cave dwellers, both in terms of stability and functionality

In other words, that TinyMCE is missing the lion's share of useful builtin APIs / plugings, including the modern one to maintain the editor's dimentions in nominally simplified way, so the only way to achieve the goal I've researched has been to utilize onInit and onChange events provided by TinyMCE3, and to maintain the whole routine with custom JavaScript handlers over the editor, applying the dimentions directly to iframes on the parent level in Magento admin page code, which Magento core utilizes as containers for TinyMCE3 instances

Anyway, the experiment has been successful, so please feel free to ask any additional practical questions or to request some tech details on routines