# How to avoid that img is cut off?

Tags: html, css

This is an issue about displaying a banner ad.

You see in In this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cqu1ywse/1/) the image is cut off.

It seems the `img`'s width is determined by the `.article-container` class. That's exactly what I want to avoid. The `img` should exceed the container's width if this is needed to be displayed correctly.

My aim is that the `img` should be *horizontally center-aligned* and that it should *not be cut off as long as the viewport's width is sufficient*.

Can anybody explain to me why the img is cut off and what to do so that the img is displayed correctly?

CSS:

```
.article {
  display: block;
} 

.article-container {
  margin-left: 25vw;
  margin-right: 25vw;
  width: 50vw;
}

.article-ad-above {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  left: -25vw;
  width: 100vw;
}

.iframe-container {
  width: 728px;
  height: 90px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<article>
  <div class="article-container">
    <h1->hallo</h1->
    <div class="article-ad-above">
      <div class="article-ad-above-inside">
        <div class="iframe-container">
          <iframe src="https://cdn.pixfuture.com/banners/728x90.gif" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" onload="" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.
    </p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: It gets cut, because you neglected to give the `iframe` that you put this in, any dimensions - so it will take [the _default_ dimensions of an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5871668/1427878), which are 300px * 150px.

Comment: give to the iframe `width:100%`so it will fit the container width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set the dimensions of the parent container to the iframe, but not the iframe itself.

- iframes are not *"aware"* of their contents and cannot resize based on the content that they display, so you *MUST* set the dimensions of the iframe itself.
- The [default dimensions for iframe (300px x 150px) are discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22844117/1690217)

The simplest change in your example is to put the `iframe-container` class on the iframe itself:

```
<iframe src="https://cdn.pixfuture.com/banners/728x90.gif" 
        frameborder="0" 
        scrolling="no" 
        onload="" 
        allowtransparency="true" 
        class="iframe-container">
</iframe>
```

See here: https://jsfiddle.net/v7oy0hzn/

---

#### Update: Debugging a Specific Example

When debugging elements that *"clip"* in you should use you browser tools to identify if the clipping is caused by a parent or the element itself.

In the example case of [apollo-news.net](https://apollo-news.net/verbotene-palaestina-demo-am-potsdamer-platz-tausend-demonstranten-kesseln-polizei-ein/) there is a parent element with a class `article-container` that is constraining *ALL* output to a column that is 50% of the viewport width.

[image]

You can see that the iframe is trying to render to your expected width, but it is not visible because it is constrained or *"clipped"* by the parent.

[image]

In that case, when there is a parent that is setting the width but you want the child element to exist outside of that boundary, then you will need to float it. (Outside of this scope of this post)

> You might want to ask yourself if it is appropriate for any content, to be visible outside of your `50vw` column... You might also ask yourself why you are using `50vw` at all, you would be better off with a fixed or min/max width for that type of content.

Comment: Thanks. You solution works perfectly in the fiddle. But the image still is cut in the "real world" (set window width to about 1000px) even if I set the iframe dimensions: https://apollo-news.net/verbotene-palaestina-demo-am-potsdamer-platz-tausend-demonstranten-kesseln-polizei-ein/ Do you have an idea what's the problem?

Comment: On that site, the iframe is actually rendering correctly, but it is clipped by a parent element. I have updated my post with details and some screenshots

Comment: Thank you so much. One last question: as you see in my fiddle there IS a class .article-container with a width of 50vw. Therefore I do not quite understand why your solution works in the fiddle but not in the real world.

Comment: in "real world" `.article-container` is putting a limit on the fixed width, making it exactly `50vw`, so in a 800px window, that's 400px, you iframe wants 728px, which is wider than that, so it doesn't fit and gets cropped by the parent. In the fiddle there are no such constraints. expand your window or zoom out, when the width is 1456px or more you will see you banner.